# How can I generate a formula in excel using tree letters then numbres for ID

Tags: excel

hope everyone is safe and sound.

I'm not great in Excel, but they ask me to create an ID Generator for the brand.
Let's say the brand's name is MOON, and they want to add an ID next to the name MOON, so it sort of like: MOON-0001, MOON-0002, so on and so on. But they want those numbers to be random.

So the table goes like:

```
Name    Country Phone   Email   Tech-ID
Alpha   USA         
Bravo   Panama          
Charlie Colombia            
Delta   Germany         
Everest Italy
```

Thanks for the help in advance

Comment: with random there is the chance that two of the same name will end up with the same id.

Comment: What output expect from your given data? What do you mean by random?

Answer (score 0):

Give a try on below formula then let us know your response.

```
=A2&RIGHT("-000"&COUNTIF($A2:$A$2,A2),5)
```

[image]